# Retrieving a select option on another page with a different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, select, local-storage

I'm trying to build a cordova app. In on of the functions, I wanted to add a dropdown select option that users can select and can get stored in order to be emailed as a request later. I added the select option in an options.html page and I wish to populate the selected option in order.html page. What would be the best way to go about this?

Here is my current options.html, which users optionsController:

```
   <md-card ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
     <img ng-src="{{items.img}}" 
          class="md-card-image" 
          alt="">
          <md-card-content class="content">
              <h2 class="md-title"><div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div></h2>
              <h4>{{ item.price | currency }}</h4>
              <h4>Qty {{ item.qty }}</h4>
              <md-list>
                  <h2 class="md-title" style="color:#3F51B5;">Select Your Side</h2>
                  <md-divider></md-divider>
                  <md-list-item layout="row">
                      <md-select aria-label="side set" class="md-accent" ng-model="item.type">
                      <md-option ng-value="side.name" ng-repeat="side in item.sides">{{ side.name }}</md-option>
                      </md-select>
                  </md-list-item>
              </md-list>
           </md-card-content>
           <md-action-bar layout="row" 
                          layout-align="end center">
                          <md-button class="md-fab md-accent fab" 
                                     aria-label="Remove From Cart" 
                                     ng-click="remove(item);showRemovedToast();"                               
                                     ng-class="{active:item.active}">
                                     <md-icon md-svg-src="img/icons/remove.svg"></md-icon>
                          </md-button>
            </md-action-bar>
      </md-card>
```

I'm retrieving JSON data under side.name, the data is as follows:

```
 var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

 app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope',
  function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.items = {
  "results": [{
    "active": false,
    "desc": "With arugula, smoked almonds \u0026 chipotle vinaigrette",
    "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Watermelon-Quinoa-Jimaca-Salad.jpg",
    "name": "Watermelon Quinoa Jicama Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightblue;\"\u003eVE\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: yellow;\"\u003eDF\u003c/span\u003e)",
    "price": 14,
    "sides": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Soup"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Salad"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Fries"
    }],
  }, {
    "active": false,
    "desc": "Buffalo mozzarella, tomato, marinated artichoke hearts, black olives, pesto \u0026 balsamic drizzle",
    "img": "https://signsrestaurant.ca/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/Mediterranean-Salad.jpg",
    "name": "Mediterranean Salad (\u003cspan style=\"color: lightgreen;\"\u003eV\u003c/span\u003e, \u003cspan style=\"color: goldenrod;\"\u003eGF\u003c/span\u003e)",
    "price": 15,
    "sides": [{
      "active": false,
      "name": "Soup"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Salad"
    }, {
      "active": false,
      "name": "Fries"
    }],
  }]
  };
  }
  ]);
```

My order.html is as follows, which uses orderController:

```
 <md-card>
  <md-card-content>
    <h3 class="md-subhead" align="center">Review And Submit Order</h3>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list ng-repeat="item in items.results | filter:true">
        <md-list-item layout="row">
            <h3><div ng-bind-html="item.name"></div> Qty:{{item.qty}}</h3>
            <span flex></span>
            <h3>{{ item.price | currency }}</h3>
        </md-list-item>
        <md-list-item layout="row">
            <div id="side"></div>
        </md-list-item>
         </md-list>
    <md-divider></md-divider>
    <md-list>
        <md-list-item layout="row">
            <h3 class="md-subhead">Order Total:</h3>
            <span flex></span>
            <h3>{{ total(items.results) | currency }}</h3>
        </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
</md-card-content>
</md-card>

<md-card ng-if="(items.results | filter : {active: true}).length > 0">
<md-card-content layout-padding>

<form name="order">
 <md-input-container flex>
  <label>Name</label>
  <input ng-model="name">
 </md-input-container>
 <md-input-container flex>
     <label>Phone</label>
  <input ng-model="phone">
 </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Address</label>
    <input ng-model="address">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Email</label>
    <input ng-model="email">
  </md-input-container>
  <md-input-container flex>
    <label>Special Requests</label>
    <textarea ng-model="requests" 
              columns="1" 
              md-maxlength="150"></textarea>
  </md-input-container>
</form>

</md-card-content>

<md-card-content layout="row"
                 layout-align="end center">

<md-button class="md-raised md-primary"
           ng-controller="EmailController"
           ng-click=sendMail()>
           Place Order
</md-button>

</md-card-content>
 </md-card>
```

I wish to populate the selected Side in the div 'side' - how do I go about this? I tried localstorage, but not sure how to store and populate on a different page. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method 1 - Using a service**

You create a service specialized in passing data among controllers/directives or other services.

**Method 2 - Using events**

Broadcast/emit an event with the data you need which you can later listen in every part of your application.

**Method 3 - Passing data as route parameter**

If you are using the angular router or ui-router (or probably any other router) you can pass data as a route paramater, which you can listen later in the controller attached to that route.

So, you can think of all this 3 methods and pick-up the one more suitable for you. In this case, you should go with the event method since you want to pass data created by an UI interaction.

Comment: Thanks! So, if I used the events method, how would I be able to add an array of ng-repeat results from json to the data? In my example, I wish to add {{ side.name }} to $rootScope$on, and then broadcast the same in another page.

Comment: It's two-way data binding, you just use the $scope.name inside another controller and when the event will be triggered just assign the passed data to it.

Comment: Thanks! I've got it figured out and it works perfectly now.
Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/4ByCDzXZfRU7kMX9oURT?p=preview

Comment: Looks good, I mean, you should probably follow a styleguide for writing angular. Don't forget to select a winning answer. cya

Answer (score 0):

### Pass values to another page, Easy way :

[how to pass more than one value to next page in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33118574/how-to-pass-more-than-one-value-to-next-page-in-angularjs/33166982#33166982)

### using broadcast:

inside controller 1

```
$scope.$root.$broadcast("triggerEvent", { pass_this_value: yourValue});
```

this is the Event listner

```
$scope.$on("triggerEvent", function (event, args) {
       //do what u want to 
});
```